# How to get the result of MySQL:[select * from mytable AS t]?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL like this:

```
SELECT m1.id1,m2.user,m3.pass,m4.cap,m5.test
FROM
(SELECT * FROM mytable) AS m1,
(SELECT * FROM mytable) AS m2,
(SELECT * FROM mytable) AS m3,
(SELECT * FROM mytable) AS m4,
(SELECT * FROM mytable) AS m5
WHERE m1.id1=m2.id2 AND m1.id1=m3.id3 AND m1.id1=m4.id4 AND m1.id1=m5.id5;
```

the table mytable is huge, but I need get all info from it, and I need get several times use the subquery, the question is: how to save the result of query(SELECT * FROM mytable) like:

```
SELECT m1.id1,m2.user,m3.pass,m4.cap,m5.test
FROM
(SELECT * FROM mytable) AS m1,
m1 AS m2,
m1 AS m3,
m1 AS m4,
m1 AS m5
WHERE m1.id1=m2.id2 AND m1.id1=m3.id3 AND m1.id1=m4.id4 AND m1.id1=m5.id5;
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT m1.id1,m2.user,m3.pass,m4.cap,m5.test
FROM mytable m1
JOIN mytable m2 ON m1.id1 = m2.id2
JOIN mytable m3 ON m1.id1 = m3.id3
JOIN mytable m4 ON m1.id1 = m4.id4
JOIN mytable m5 ON m1.id1 = m5.id5
```

Comment: You're the fastest at tis sideof the Colorado!

Answer (score 1):

The right way would be to use `JOIN` and let the optimizer do his job:

```
SELECT m1.id1,m2.user,m3.pass,m4.cap,m5.test
  FROM mytable as m1
  JOIN mytable as m2 ON m1.id1=m2.id2
  JOIN mytable as m3 ON m1.id1=m3.id3
  JOIN mytable as m4 ON m1.id1=m4.id4
  JOIN mytable as m5 ON m1.id1=m5.id5 ;
```

It has no sense to use a subquery to select all the data from a table....